# Windows Server Core: how could I disable CTRL+ALT+DEL on logon?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016, windows-server-core

I am trying a VM of Windows Server Core on KVM on Linux. My problem is what looks like a bug of virt-manager, it can't send ctrl-alt-del when i press the button "send ctrl-alt-del", so I can't login anymore after the very first boot.

How could I disable CTRL+ALT+DEL on logon?

I tried to disable it on the registry, but it did not work

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\DisableCAD is already set to 1

Comment: "CANC" = Italian for "DEL"?

Comment: @marsh-wiggle shoot, i translated wrong, i am going to fix it :D

Comment: Perhaps check the GPO equivalent key:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\DisableCAD

Comment: @Dan it works! (the screen "press ctrl-alt-del to login" still appears, but it goes away just by pressing any key)